# Zookeeper DNS name problems with leader elections when migrating from Windows to Debian

Tags: debian, dns, ip, cluster

I am migrating a kafka/zookeeper cluster on Windows to Debian wheezy.

- Java version: 1.7.0_80
- Debian version: 7.9
- Zookeeper version: 3.3.5+dfsg1-2 0
- Kafka version: 2.10-0.8.2.1

If I configure zookeeper on the Debian servers with IP addresses for the other Debian servers, everything works fine. If I use DNS names instead, the leader election fails on the Debian servers.

On the Debian servers, I can lookup the IP of any of the other Debian servers using 'host' command, so DNS resolution is working.

Everything is automated: server creation, Debian installation, zookeeper installation, zookeeper configuration; so the window for manual config errors are at a bare minimum and easy to reproduce or change.

Using `clientPortAddress=DNSNAME` does not make any difference; it still fails.
There is nothing configured in iptables. There is no firewall in between these servers.

In the following, servers 1-3 are Windows 2012R2 servers and servers 4-6 are Debian servers.

**This config works:**

```
 server.1=testkafka400:2888:3888
 server.2=testkafka401:2888:3888
 server.3=testkafka402:2888:3888
 server.4=10.1.132.152:2888:3888
 server.5=10.1.132.153:2888:3888
 server.6=10.1.132.154:2888:3888
```

**This config does not work:**

```
 server.1=testkafka400:2888:3888
 server.2=testkafka401:2888:3888
 server.3=testkafka402:2888:3888
 server.4=testkafka403:2888:3888
 server.5=testkafka404:2888:3888
 server.6=testkafka405:2888:3888
```

When I use the DNS names, I get the following output -- where the exceptions just repeat themselves. Please note that the following log is from a cluster setup containing *only* Debian servers, using DNS names, for the sake of testing. If I shift to IP, the cluster works and can hold an election.

```
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,309] INFO Reading configuration from: /etc/zookeeper/config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,322] INFO Defaulting to majority quorums (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,344] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,344] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 24 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,345] INFO Purge task started. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,454] INFO Purge task completed. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,472] INFO Starting quorum peer (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,581] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,601] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,601] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,601] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,601] INFO initLimit set to 20 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,626] INFO Reading snapshot /etc/zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,675] INFO My election bind port: testkafka403.prod.local/127.0.1.1:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,713] INFO LOOKING (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,715] INFO New election. My id =  4, proposed zxid=0x100000014 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,717] INFO Notification: 1 (message format version), 4 (n.leader), 0x100000014 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 4 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,732] WARN Cannot open channel to 5 at election address testkafka404.prod.local/10.1.132.153:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.remainingMillis(SocksSocketImpl.java:111)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:341)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:449)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:430)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,737] WARN Cannot open channel to 6 at election address testkafka405.prod.local/10.1.132.154:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.toSend(QuorumCnxManager.java:341)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.process(FastLeaderElection.java:449)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerSender.run(FastLeaderElection.java:430)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-11-03 13:55:52,919] WARN Cannot open channel to 6 at election address testkafka405.prod.local/10.1.132.154:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:368)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:402)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:840)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:762)
```

We really would like to be able to use DNS names, but have no clue as to where we should begin looking for a solution any more. Maybe we missed installing or activating an important Debian or Java feature?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a Debian issue. I see the same thing with zookeeper 3.4.6 on centos 7 running openjdk 8 (1.8.0u65, to be exact).

Are your Debian hosts running OpenJDK or Oracle Java?

Comment: Oracle java. But the hosts file solved the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I have an idea of what's going on here. I saw the same issue when trying to set up a 3-node Spring-XD cluster in Vagrant, on Linux VMs.

This configuration worked:

```
server.1=172.28.128.3:2888:3888
server.2=172.28.128.4:2888:3888
server.3=172.28.128.7:2888:3888
```

But this one didn't:

```
server.1=spring-xd-1:2888:3888
server.2=spring-xd-2:2888:3888
server.3=spring-xd-3:2888:3888
```

The "smoking gun" was this line in my zookeeper log:

> 2015-11-26 20:48:31,439 [myid:1] - INFO 
>   [Thread-2:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@504] - My election bind port:
>   spring-xd-1/127.0.0.1:3888

So, why was Zookeeper binding the election port on the loopback interface? Well...

My `/etc/hosts` on one of the VMs looked like this:

```
127.0.0.1   spring-xd-1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
172.28.128.3    spring-xd-1
172.28.128.4    spring-xd-2
172.28.128.7    spring-xd-3
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

I removed the hostname from the `127.0.0.1` line in `/etc/hosts` and bounced the zookeeper service on all 3 nodes, and **BAM!** everything came up roses. So, now the host file on each machine looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
172.28.128.3    spring-xd-1
172.28.128.4    spring-xd-2
172.28.128.7    spring-xd-3
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

I'm guessing you didn't see the issue on Windows because the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) has no entries by default. You should be able to reproduce the problem on Windows, by adding a similar `127.0.0.1` line to it.

<strike>I'm calling this a Zookeeper bug. Editing the hosts file was good enough to prove out the issue and remediate it in Vagrant, but I wouldn't recommend it for any "real" environment.</strike>

**EDIT:** According to http://ccl.cse.nd.edu/operations/condor/hostname.shtml, this seems to be a fairly common problem with clustered apps on Linux, and recommends editing the hosts file as I've described above. However, the [Zookeeper documentation on cluster setup](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) doesn't mention it.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense, I will test it and get back :)

Comment: It took a while to get it tested but it worked :)

Comment: Actually in my case the hosts file had 127.0.1.1 entry which appears to be a debian thing. Stripping that line away solved the issue. See http://serverfault.com/questions/363095/why-does-my-hostname-appear-with-the-address-127-0-1-1-rather-than-127-0-0-1-in for deeper explanation of the 127.0.1.1 issue.

Comment: Spent a day on this.. Thanks a lot this works...

Answer (score 2):

Probably this issue caused by setting node `hostname` to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. In this case ZK will bind `leader|election ports` to `127.0.0.1` address.

Config param `quorumListenOnAllIPs=true` should remedy this issue and bind `election|leader ports` to `0.0.0.0`.

More options and their impact can be found in [ZK administration guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/zookeeperAdmin.html)

It is always good to check [source code](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/branch-3.4/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerConfig.java#L166).